# HPNonStop RestService Deployment

Tags: rest, tomcat, deployment, hp-nonstop

I build a Rest Service using Jersey and deploying it locally in Tomcat 6 it's working  fine but When I am deploying into Hp-nonstop( I believe Tomcat 6)  It's not coming up. Can you please help me with that.
I also tried to deploy an application with one static JSP and it's working fine on HP-nonStop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's environment issue. I am using JDK1.5 and tomcat6.

It resolved by doing two step
1)  I included a activation.jar file into project

2) I have to remove xml-apis.jar , xercesImpl.jar files from  \ common\ endorsed